# R: How to read an oracle spatial database?

Tags: r, oracle, odbc, r-sf

I would like to read an oracle spatial database from R.
This database contains a column with geometry : 
geometry1 : MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(655081,618975579,6861651,4067522,0,655083,444176393,6861649,74471328,0,655094,644962858,6861639,54520924,0,655109,121754127,6861626,36255537,0,655115,951718724,6861620,09729273,0)

I have access to the database but cannot read this column

```
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), database ="Database_oracle", UID="id", PWD="pw")
```

this works:

```
data <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT ID
               FROM TABLE_1") %>% 
as_tibble()
```

but this doens't :

```
data <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT ID, geometry1
               FROM TABLE_1") %>% 
as_tibble()
```

ORA-01024:     invalid datatype in OCI call

Is there a way to read the coordinates with sf::st_read ?
do I have to use in my SQL query some "SDO_GEOMETRY()" function to extract the coordinates ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the `sf` package only supports Postgres databases for directly retrieving geometry columns.

One thing you can do is attach the `Get_WKT()` method in your query to convert the geometry to "Well-Known Text", like this:

```
data <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT ID, geometry1.Get_WKT() FROM TABLE1")

# Then
st_as_sf(data, wkt = 2)  # set `wkt` parameter to column index
```

note that the projection information is lost here, you'll need to add it afterwards. Hope this helps!

edit: here is a link to Oracle's SDO_GEOMETRY methods - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-methods.htm#SPATL498

Comment: When I used Get.WKT  =>  "3D geometries are not supported by geometry WKB/WKT generation"  I was abble to extract the coordinates with dbGetQuery(con, "select ID, sdo_util.to_gmlgeometry(geometry1) as test from TABLE1") and some extraction in that string