# How to read an sdo_geometry column?

Tags: r, odbc

I have a spatial table in Oracle with one sdo_geometry() column. When I querying this table with dbi/odbc I get "error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655". It is possible to fetch the non-sdo_geometry columns. What do I need to do?

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
    driver = "Oracle in OraClient12Home1",
    DBQ  = "database",
    UID     = "username",
    PWD = "password")

dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT GEOMETRY FROM SPATIALTABLE")
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get R to read the geometry in SDO_GEOMETRY format. The best I could do was convert to Well-Known Text when reading, then you can convert that to a geometry column in whatever package you are using.

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(GEOMETRY) as GEOMETRY FROM SPATIALTABLE")
```

[Oracle - Converting SDO_GEOMETRY to WKT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832223/oracle-converting-sdo-geometry-to-wkt)

[R: How to read an oracle spatial database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594135/r-how-to-read-an-oracle-spatial-database)